# AWS: no web app firewall for ALB in Sydney region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I tried to create a WAF for our Sydney ALB and found it is not available so I have to create cloudfront to be able to use WAF. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in the Syndey Region you'll need to create Cloudfront distribution.

AWS WAF for CloudFront is available for all regions. **AWS WAF for use with an Application Load Balancer is available for the following regions**:

```
US East (N. Virginia)

US West (N. California)

US West (Oregon)

EU (Ireland)

Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll need to create a CloudFront Distribution.

From [Product Details](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/details/)

"With AWS WAF you first identify the resource (either an Amazon CloudFront distribution or an Application Load Balancer) that you need to protect"

From [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/faq/):

12. In what Regions is AWS WAF on ALB available in?
    US East (Northern Virginia), US West (North California), US West (Oregon), Asia Pacific (Tokyo) and EU (Ireland)